# Create a stack of items

Tags: arrays, plain-tex

In plain TeX, how do I create a stack of items? 
I need to be able to push items to the end of the list, pop items and output the full list of items.

For example

```
\createlist{\mylist}
\push{\mylist}{A}
\push{\mylist}{-B}
\push{\mylist}{-C}
\print{\mylist}   % prints A-B-C
\pop{\mylist}     % Removes `-C'
\print{\mylist}   % prints A-B
```

I found `listings.sty` which seems to have pushing (with `\lst@lAddToa`) but not popping (although I am not sure as the documentation of this functionality is thin).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A would expect a stack to build up from the front not the end, so here I reverse the stack for `\print`

[image]

This assumes the tokens in the items are safe in an `\edef`

```
\catcode`\!=4
\def\createlist#1{\def#1{}}
\def\push#1#2{\edef#1{#2!#1}}
\def\pop#1{\edef#1{\expandafter\xpop#1}}
\def\xpop#1!{}
\def\print#1{\expandafter\xprint#1!\xpop!\relax}
\def\xprint#1!#2\relax{\ifx\xpop#1\else\xprint#2\relax#1\fi}
\catcode`\!=12


\createlist{\mylist}

\push{\mylist}{A}

\push{\mylist}{-B}

\push{\mylist}{-C}

\print{\mylist}   % prints A-B-C

\pop{\mylist}     % Removes `-C'

\print{\mylist}   % prints A-B


\bye
```

Comment: I absolutely love this solution. I am sill learning `tex` and the idea of using `!` and `\def` parsing to find the next item is genius.

Comment: I am trying to modify the script to include a `\lastpop` (mainly to test my understanding of you script). I thought I could just do `\def\xpop#1!{\def\lastpop{#1}}`, so that when an item is discarded it is saved in `\lastpop` (I think I probably will have to define a separate command that is used in `pop` than `print` to avoid overriding `lastpop` when printing). However, that doesn't seem to work since the `\def` command inside `\xpop` seems to never be called.

Comment: @Tohiko you would have to re-arrange it slightly to do the `\edef` of te rest of the stack later, I do it inside the edef here so you can not do a non-expandable assignment of the popped value

Comment: Ah I see. I think I figured it out (although there are probably more elegant solutions).  `\def\pop#1{\expandafter\deflastpop#1\relax  
  \edef#1{\expandafter\xpop#1}}  
\def\deflastpop#1!#2\relax{\def\lastpop{#1}  
  \xignore#2!\xignore!\relax}  
\def\xignore#1!#2\relax{\ifx\xignore#1\else\xignore#2\relax\fi}`

Comment: @Tohiko Not tested, but something like `\def\pop#1{\expandafter\xpop#1\xpop#1} \def\xpop#1!#2\xpop#3{\def\lastpop{#1}\def#3{#2}}` should do, with the restriction that you cannot have `\xpop` in an item of the stack. Also note that with your code you can't have `\relax`

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness, if you're using a TeX engine with ε-TeX (that is, not Knuth TeX), then you can use `seq` variables from `expl3`, which have most of the stack functionality you want:

```
\input expl3-generic

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \lastpop
\cs_new_eq:NN \createlist \seq_new:N
\cs_new_eq:NN \push \seq_push:Nn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pop #1
  { \seq_pop:NN #1 \lastpop }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \print #1
  {
    \tl_clear:N \lastpop
    \seq_map_inline:Nn #1
      { \tl_put_left:Nn \lastpop {##1} }
    \tl_use:N \lastpop
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\createlist{\mylist}
\push{\mylist}{A}
\push{\mylist}{-B}
\push{\mylist}{-C}
\print{\mylist}   % prints A-B-C
\pop{\mylist}     % Removes `-C' (`-C' is available in \lastpop)
\print{\mylist}   % prints A-B

\bye
```